# Force Stop by Error in httpClient.execute(httpPost);

Tags: java, android

It work's at Smartphone(Android 2.3.3) but Tablet(Android 4.0) => Force Close!!

```
 public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost); // HERE FORCE CLOSE, why???
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}
```

Any suggestion with example?

Comment: Try adding yet another catch block like this: `catch (Throwable t) { t.printStackTrace(); }` Then see what it prints to your error log.

Comment: because you are networking on the uithread. next time : read the stacktrace, find the exception name, google it.

Answer (score 2):

You should remember this.

> From Android 3.x Honeycomb or later, you cannot perform Network IO on
>   the UI thread and doing this throws
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. You must use **Asynctask**
>   .

You have to put your `getXmlFromUrl(..)` code inside **Asynctask** method

For more Information Refer this Link
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html